# using array to rm file in bash

Tags: bash

Hi I am using an array to hold details of songs on my hard drive and then using rm to remove the file if I have more than one copy (this is checked at another place in the script) with the details held in the array, but I keep getting the error no file or directory

After my songs or song is loaded into the array I test the value of the array

```
echo "song store in array "${myarray[$d]}
```

this produces

```
song store in array /media/sdate/music/Disco 80's/013. Donna Summer - She Works Hard For The Money.mp3
```

Then I run

```
rm {myarray[$d]}
rm: cannot remove ‘/media/sdate/music/Disco 80's/013. Donna Summer - She Works Hard For The Money.mp3 ’: No such file or directory
```

I have tried

```
rm {myarray[$d]}
rm "{myarray[$d]}"
rm `{myarray[$d]}`
```

but still no joy.

Comment: I'm not sure that `rm {myarray[$d]}` would produce that output - you're missing a `$` there. `rm "${myarray[$d]}"` would be the correct syntax - does that work?

Comment: `3 ’` - what's that space?

Comment: used "${myarray[$d]}" but still not working

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to get the array element at index `$d` is

```
${myarray[d]}
```

To prevent the shell from splitting the string on spaces, doublequote it:

```
rm "${myarray[d]}"
```

(You can use $ before `d` in the index, but it's not necessary.)

Comment: I just tried rm "${myarray[d]}" but still no joy. is the  ` being added before the rm command work or do i have to remove the ` and if so how?

Comment: @AndrewSams: and then what happened?

Comment: As far as i can tell the variable with the song in it has no spaces at beginning or end. when i run the script with this rm "${myarray[d]}" i get the same error.

Comment: @AndrewSams: How do you populate the array?

Comment: Hi i populate the array with while read line           
do           
  a=$(echo -e "$line " | cut -d" " -f2- ) # variable a hold the directory and song name
  echo "song number "$i "is " $a
  myarray[$A]=${a}
  A=$((A+1))  
  
done < list.txt

Comment: `$(...)` can change whitespace.